# Last Sunday of March and October

Tags: oracle

I want to populate a table ---one column having the date for  last Sunday of March and October for each year from 1800 to 2050 ..

Can someone help?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT NEXT_DAY(LAST_DAY(SYSDATE)-7, 'SUN') FROM DUAL;
```

This gives the last date of the current month.

You just need to loop through the months instead of just giving SYSDATE.

Comment: can u write send the query/funcation